# Checkout URL Order Token no longer matches actual Order Token (recent change?)

Tags: shopify

First thanks for taking the time to read.

I used to be able to use the Order Token in the check out URL to do a API look up and create my own browser invoice for an order. E.G.

1. checkout.shopify.com/orders/STOREID/ORDER_TOKEN_723b06712768bb037b2b
2. Using the ORDER_TOKEN_723b06712768bb037b2b I create a query string:

invoice.php?order_token=ORDER_TOKEN_723b06712768bb037b2b

1. invoice.php I loop through all the orders made in the last 30 minutes using an API call. Then I do a simple match on my results, if any of the order tokens from my api call match ORDER_TOKEN_723b06712768bb037b2b then I know I have the right order and I can print out details.

This worked up until a few months ago. Now order tokens still come back from the API call but they never match.

Any ideas?

How can I use the order token in the check out URL to match an order?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be more precise, there are two tokens available with an Order.

```
cart_token   - which is matching the **cart** value of the customer's session
token        - possibly is the token used during checkout you refer to as order_token?
```

To gain some insight into your problem then:

1. When you speak of an order_token, you are speaking of the token attribute of an order?
2. If they differ, the question is then, what is the token value representative of? By that I mean the value from the checkout and the value assigned to an order.

Comment: Q: When you speak of an order_token, you are speaking of the token attribute of an order? 
A: The attribute of an order E.G.: $the_order['token']

Q: If they differ, the question is then, what is the token value representative of? By that I mean the value from the checkout and the value assigned to an order.

A: That's what I need to figure out. Why was this working before? The only thing I have to work with us the value at the end of the checkout URL, i.e.: "ORDER_TOKEN_723b06712768bb037b2b" as in my example above.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify added a checkout API (see http://www.shopify.com/technology/6735056-upcoming-api-changes), which may be why things are different.  You are probably referring to the token of the checkout and not the token of the order or vice versa.